# missing keyword at keyword in Antlr Lab

Tags: antlr4

```
grammar Hello;
r : 'hello' ID ;
ID : [a-z]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Input:
hello world

Error:
1:0 missing 'hello' at 'hello'

I followed the code carefully... ive tried editing the code and it did not work.

Im a beginner with no compiler experience so can you please explain the error and give me tips on how to make levers using antler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the grammar. You probably didn't see the `Lexer` tab.

[image]

Just remove everything you see in the `Lexer` tab.